# nginx http_mp4_module pseudostreaming

Tags: nginx, video-streaming

I'm using Nginx 1.2.3 with http_mp4_module installed and trying to make pseudostreaming server using it. When I'm trying to set start position less than *25* everything works like a charm:

```
http://192.168.56.101/my_video.mp4?start=20
```

But when I set start more than 25 I'm getting this error in error log:

```
2012/08/14 17:15:21 [error] 20091#0: *8 start sample is out of mp4 stss atom in "/home/bender/my_video.mp4", client: 192.168.56.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /my_video.mp4?start=25 HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.56.101"
```

All videos I have tested have more than 60 seconds duration, so I don't think it's because of out of duration ranges.

Comment: I had a similar problem, fixed it by making bigger max_buffer_size :)

Answer (score 1):

The error message suggests the file doesn't have enough information in stss (stream sync samples) atom.  Looks like problem with the file and/or mp4 creation process used.